# could not connect with google cloud storage

Tags: mysql, database, azure, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I have just created cloud storage on `google` for `mysql` database.
I have added local IP address and server's IP address in authorization (under access control).

It's getting connected in mysql work bench in my local machine. But, it's not connecting with the website which is running on windows azure platform.

Which IP address am I supposed to use in access control?

Website is in basic package of azure.

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to set up Google Cloud SQL or use Google Cloud Storage buckets? If the former, try this doc: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/getting-started

Comment: I went through above link and video. I am just confused in which IP address should I provice in access control if my application is on windows azure platform?

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively non-trivial thing to achieve as the GCP services need to know about the public source IP of the Azure service. Azure's IP surface is pretty wide so you'd be unlikely to successfully connect the two. You'll be unlikely to be able use just a single source IP address.

You may be better off looking at a [VPN connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn) out of an Azure VNet to your GCP environment.

To be honest, trying to build any form of performant web experience that hosts the web and data tiers in different public clouds is going to be extremely challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I resolved this issue by opening ticket in azure support.
They have outbound IP addresses range available online. We need to provide those IP addresses to third party access control.

I am sharing you that link here.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Choose those IP addresses which are associated with your website.